# Is there a way to reset player stats and league in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

I haven't played StarCraft II for a long, long time and I would like to get back into it as a very casual player.

My problem is that I played a lot before and somehow landed in diamond league.

I lost all my placement matches and then about 10 more after that and I am **still** in diamond league.

My performance is so bad that my opponents don't enjoy the game either.

Does anybody know if there is a reset stats and league option or the best way to play against players around my skill level?

Comment: Buy a new copy of the game, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be moving down the rankings, but you won't move to a new division until your hidden Elo somewhat stabilizes. So just keep playing, you'll keep losing, and when you start winning every other game or so, you'll get dropped down to the level of those players.

SC2's matchmaking system tries not too move you too much, so when it detects a large fluctuation from where it expects you to be, it will wait until it's pretty sure where you belong before actually moving you there.

Comment: What is a hidden Elo?

Comment: I believe you mean HMR, Elo I think is LoL

Comment: @Nick122 Elo is just a generic term for rating, since pretty much every matchmaking system is based off the Elo system to some degree. Hidden just means that you aren't able to determine what it is. LoL's Elo rating is not hidden, for instance. You can refer to it however you'd like, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: MMR (MatchMaking Rating) is the term used for Blizzard games hidden ranking system

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.

Give it some time.  The best advice I can give is to warn your opponents that you're just getting back into the game, and that you're not really diamond league material anymore.  If they are angry with you for that then let them be angry... kind of stupid to get angry over someone getting back into the game.

After a week or so you should fall to a different league.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not really in diamond league anymore. The system won't demote you till it is confident that if figures out where you belong. I was bored and wanted to fool around in bronze league. I was leaving games nonstop right after they started. Eventually I was facing silver league opponents even thought I was still in diamond league. Once I beat some of them it demoted me to silver.